# Dropdown menu increases div's length instead of popping up

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am using https://getmdl.io/ in my site, and I have a header. My problem is that, when I press on the dropdown menu, instead of the dropdown menu to pop up, it increases header's size and scrollbar appears. Do you have any suggestions?

[Having clicked dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpCYu.png)

code:

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">MyPage.net</a>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label getmdl-select">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input" id="country" name="country" value="Belarus" type="text" readonly tabIndex="-1" data-val="BLR"/>
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="country">Country</label>
          <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu" for="country">
            <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="BLR">Belarus</li>
            <li class="mdl-menu__item" data-val="RUS">Russia</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Give us a working demo please. We need the minimum amount of code needed to replicate the issue in your post. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: You are absolute right. I should have added in the first post https://jsfiddle.net/9ppxyswc/